# Adding 3rd Dynamic drop down menu

Tags: php, javascript

I already have this code working for 2 selection menus, now I am trying to add a third but the third is just showing all of the sub-sub categories, rather than being based on the previous selections..

Here is the menu code, I'll just show 1 selection example so it's easier to read.

```
<select name="category" id="category">
  <option value="Sport">Sport</option>
</select>

<select name="sub_category" id="sub_category">
  <option value="Golf" class="Sport">Golf</option>
</select>

<select name="subsub_category" id="subsub_category">
  <option value="Mens" class="Golf">Mens</option>
  <option value="Ladies" class="Golf">Ladies</option>
</select>
```

JS CODE

```
<script src="js/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        dynamicSelect("category", "sub_category", "subsub_category");
    }
    </script>
```

MENU.JS

```
function dynamicSelect(id1, id2, id3) {
// Browser and feature tests to see if there is enough W3C DOM support
var agt = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var is_ie = ((agt.indexOf("msie") != -1) && (agt.indexOf("opera") == -1));
var is_mac = (agt.indexOf("mac") != -1);
if (!(is_ie && is_mac) && document.getElementById && document.getElementsByTagName) {
    // Obtain references to both select boxes
    var sel1 = document.getElementById(id1);
    var sel2 = document.getElementById(id2);
    var sel3 = document.getElementById(id3);
    // Clone the dynamic select box
    var clone = sel3.cloneNode(true);
    // Obtain references to all cloned options 
    var clonedOptions = clone.getElementsByTagName("option");
    // Onload init: call a generic function to display the related options in the dynamic select box
    refreshDynamicSelectOptions(sel1, sel2, sel3, clonedOptions);
    // Onchange of the main select box: call a generic function to display the related options in the dynamic select box
    sel1.onchange = function() {
        refreshDynamicSelectOptions(sel1, sel2, sel3, clonedOptions);
    };
}
}
function refreshDynamicSelectOptions(sel1, sel2, sel3 clonedOptions) {
// Delete all options of the dynamic select box
while (sel2.options.length) {
    sel2.remove(0);
}
// Create regular expression objects for "select" and the value of the selected   option of the main select box as class names
var pattern1 = /( |^)(select)( |$)/;
var pattern2 = new RegExp("( |^)(" + sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex].value + ")(  |$)");
var pattern3 = new RegExp("( |^)(" + sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex].value + ")( |$)");
// Iterate through all cloned options
for (var i = 0; i < clonedOptions.length; i++) {
    // If the classname of a cloned option either equals "select" or equals  the value of the selected option of the main select box
    if (clonedOptions[i].className.match(pattern1) || clonedOptions[i].className.match(pattern2)  || clonedOptions[i].className.match(pattern3))     {
        // Clone the option from the hidden option pool and append it to the dynamic select box
        sel2.appendChild(clonedOptions[i].cloneNode(true));
        sel3.appendChild(clonedOptions[i].cloneNode(true));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Had to change a lot to get it working, but it is working now, here: http://jsfiddle.net/kvAWf/11/

Here's the resulting Javascript:

```
var sel1 = document.getElementById('category');
var sel2 = document.getElementById('sub_category');
var sel3 = document.getElementById('subsub_category');
// Clone the dynamic select box
var clone2 = sel2.cloneNode(true);
var clone3 = sel3.cloneNode(true);
// Obtain references to all cloned options 
var clonedOptions2 = clone2.getElementsByTagName("option");
var clonedOptions3 = clone3.getElementsByTagName("option");
sel1.onchange = function(){
    refreshSelect2();
}
sel2.onchange = function(){
    refreshSelect3();
}

function refreshSelect2() {
    while (sel2.options.length) {
        sel2.remove(0);
    }
    var pattern2 = new RegExp("( |^)(" + sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex].value + ")( |$)");
    for (var i = 0; i < clonedOptions2.length; i++) {
        // If the classname of a cloned option either equals "select" or equals  the value of the selected option of the main select box
        if (clonedOptions2[i].className.match(pattern2))     {
            // Clone the option from the hidden option pool and append it to the dynamic select box
            sel2.appendChild(clonedOptions2[i].cloneNode(true));
        }
    }
    refreshSelect3();
}


function refreshSelect3() { 
    while (sel3.options.length) {
        sel3.remove(0);
    }
    var pattern3 = new RegExp("( |^)(" + sel2.options[sel2.selectedIndex].value + ")( |$)");
    for (var i = 0; i < clonedOptions3.length; i++) {
        // If the classname of a cloned option either equals "select" or equals  the value of the selected option of the main select box
        if (clonedOptions3[i].className.match(pattern3))     {
            // Clone the option from the hidden option pool and append it to the dynamic select box
            sel3.appendChild(clonedOptions3[i].cloneNode(true));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the post, I missed that one, still not working :( it's showing all of the sel2 options in the second window regardless of what I chose in the first.

Comment: Ok, I had another look and think I figured it out. I've added an update to my answer, let me know how it goes :)

Comment: Thanks for your time, I added in the code you provided and still no go :( in the subcategory menu it's displaying all of the subcategory results, regardless of what was selected in the 1st menu, and the 3rd is letting me choose any of the options and seems to be ignoring the first 2 menus :(

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what's up with that, though there are a few places it could be going wrong (I also noticed you didn't emove all the options from sel3). If you want to make a jsFiddle I wouldn't mind taking a deeper look.

Comment: I just did, added a few diff options so you could see what was going on. http://jsfiddle.net/wd5CF/

Comment: Ok, take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/kvAWf/11/
Had to change a lot to get it working, but take from it what you will :P

Comment: Thank you for your work, it's working in the example window just not working on the live site >_< 

Does

    // window.onload = dynamicSelect("category", "sub_category", "subsub_category");


Go in the <head></head> to replace window.onload = function() {
   dynamicSelect("category", "sub_category", "subsub_category");
  }  ?

Comment: Oh yeah. Get rid of `window.onload = dynamicSelect("category", "sub_category", "subsub_category");` and put all of the code from the jsFiddle either in window.onload, or at the end of the file. Should work then.

Comment: Not sure what I have done wrong, 2nd menu is showing correctly based on 1st option, but the third shows the 2 options no matter what else is selected in the previous menus.

Comment: You have both the refreshSelect2 and refreshSelect3 functions defined, right? Should be more or less exactly like the JS here: http://jsfiddle.net/kvAWf/12/

Comment: Going off your link you have  onChange="" set on the 1st category then there is no onChange on the other 2 menus, is that correct?

Comment: Yep it's fine, `onChange=""` is the same as having no `onChange`.

Comment: No worries, glad you got there in the end.